# How do I save an image created by pChart to a file?

Tags: php, pchart

I am using the following:

```
$chartImage->autoOutput('/statistics/'.$image.'.png');
```

The problem is that this code outputs the image to the browser. I would prefer it if it saved the image to a file with the directory and name I specified. How do I do this? I was looking at the pChart wiki, and its very confusing with all this pCache stuff. I don't have a need for any caching or anything like that... I just want to save the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$chartImage->render("image_name.png");
```

It worked for me in 1.x, don't know about 2.x - did not used it.

Comment: Thanks, that did it... the render function does not appear to be documented in the pChart wiki.

Comment: Hmm.. Here it is: http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.faq.script.output.html See 'Rendering to a flat file'.

Comment: It worked for me.But image quality is not good.How do I get quality image?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no way, then do

```
ob_start();
$chartImage->autoOutput('/statistics/'.$image.'.png');
$image = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$file = fopen('<path_to_file>', 'wb');
fputs($file, $image);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$imageOut = 'grafico';
$chart->drawFromJPG($width, $height, "{$imageOut}.jpg");
$chart->render("{$imageOut}.jpg");
```

I got this working very well.